# Get all values of a key in a nested array of objects using ramda.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested, ramda.js

I am a little confused in how to proceed with this scenario using ramda. Here is the JSON that I am working with.

`{
   "type" : "CartWsDTO",

   "Cartentries" : [ {
      "entryNumber" : 1,
      "flightGroup" : {
         "PAXDetails" : [ {
            "paxID" : "1",
            "paxPrice" : "770.82",
            "paxType" : "ADT"
         }, {
            "paxID" : "2",
            "paxPrice" : "770.82",
            "paxType" : "ADT"
         } ]
      }
   }, {
      "entryNumber" : 2,
      "flightGroup" : {
         "PAXDetails" : [ {
            "paxID" : "1",
            "paxName" : "Vinitha",
            "paxPrice" : "770.82",
            "paxSurname" : "Vinitha",
            "paxType" : "ADT"
         }, {
            "paxID" : "2",
            "paxName" : "Prahal",
            "paxPrice" : "770.82",
            "paxSurname" : "Prahal",
            "paxType" : "ADT"
         } ]
      }
   } ]
}`

There are 2 CartEnteries in the above JSON. There is an array named paxDetails in flightGroup of each entry. From this paxDetails array I want to pick the paxPrice and make a sum of all the pax prices for that cart entry. In traditional for loop and if conditions I am able to achieve it. But using Ramda I couldn't understand how to start with. Kindly provide me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're looking for as output.  Here's a solution that simply returns the sum of the two sets of prices and returns an array with those values:

```
var calcTotals = R.pipe(
    R.prop('Cartentries'),
    R.map(R.pipe(
        R.path(['flightGroup', 'PAXDetails']),
        R.map(R.pipe(R.prop('paxPrice'), Number)),
        R.sum
    ))
);
calcTotals(cart); //=> [1541.64, 1541.64]
```

But if you wanted a different sort of output, such as

```
{1: 1541.64, 2: 1541.64}
```

or

```
[{entryNumber : 1, total: 1541.64}, {entryNumber: 2. total: 1541.64}]
```

or whatever, you'd have to make some changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is what exactly I wanted.. This saved my time. I think I should get deeper understanding of the API to perform these things.